# How to call html file from a jsp page using iframe

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to call an html file from a jsp page. The HTML file contains d3.js code which displays a chart. I am calling this HTML file in IFRAME tag but it doesn't populate. Can somebody please me on this?

Here is my JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <title>
      Cluster Dendrogram
   </title>
   <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png">
   <style>
      @import url("/style.css?20120730");
      header,
      footer {
      color: #555;
      }
      a.gist {
      color: #000;
      }
      .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
      }
      .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      }
      .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      }
   </style>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <header>
      <a class="gist" title="View gist #4063570 on GitHub" href="https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063570">
      #4063570
      </a>
      <span class="date">
      November 13, 2012
      </span>
   </header>
   <body>
      <iframe src="/MVPApplication/WebContent/WEB_INF/test2.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="600" height="700" scrolling="no">
      </iframe>
      <footer>
         <span class="date">
         November 13, 2014
         </span>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>


Here is the HTML file that I am trying to call(test2.HTML)



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>
      <style>
         .node circle {
         fill: #fff;
         stroke: steelblue;
         stroke-width: 3px;
         }
         .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }
         .link {
         fill: none;
         stroke: #ccc;
         stroke-width: 2px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <div>
      <!-- load the d3.js library --> 
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
         var margin = {top: 80, right: 200, bottom: 20, left: 260},
           width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
           height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

         var i = 0;

         var tree = d3.layout.tree()
           .size([height, width]);

         var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
           .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

         var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
           .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
           .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
           .append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

         // load the external data
         d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, data) {

         // *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
         // create a name: node map
         var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
           map[node.name] = node;
           return map;
         }, {});

         // create the tree array
         var treeData = [];
         data.forEach(function(node) {
           // add to parent
           var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
           if (parent) {
             // create child array if it doesn't exist
             (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
               // add node to child array
               .push(node);
           } else {
             // parent is null or missing
             treeData.push(node);
           }
         });

           root = treeData[0];
           update(root);
         });



         function update(source) {

           // Compute the new tree layout.
           var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
             links = tree.links(nodes);


           // Normalize for fixed-depth.
           nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 150; });

           // Declare the nodesâ€¦
           var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
             .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });15  // Enter the nodes.
           var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
             .attr("class", "node")
             .attr("transform", function(d) { 
               return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

           nodeEnter.append("circle")
             .attr("r", 10)
             .style("fill", "#fff");

              /* nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("y", function(d) { 
             return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);*/

           nodeEnter.append("text")
             .attr("x", function(d) { 
               return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
             .attr("dy", ".35em")
             .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
               return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
             .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
             .style("fill-opacity", 1);

           // Declare the linksâ€¦
           var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
             .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

           // Enter the links.
           link.enter().insert("path", "g")
             .attr("class", "link")
             .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.target.level; })
             .attr("d", diagonal);



         }

      </script>
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your directory structure here?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<iframe src="test2.HTML" scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Hi Tanjima-My JSP file is in the webcontent folder(inside that a jsp folder) and HTML file is in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Hey Tanjima- Thank you for giving this code but it does not work as my files are in separate locations

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: @Beginner, can you please define "does not work"? Are you getting an error or just a blank page/frame?

Comment: Tanjima- I cannot place a screenshot. I'll try to describe it. WebContent->JSP folder->My JSP file. And WebContent->Web-INF->My HTML file

Comment: What you can try is (in your browser) - right-click the main page and go to the properties to see the full address. The do the same inside the iframe, and if you actually get an address for the iframe - check what's missing and add it to the iframe definition (e.g. src="/subfolder/anotherfolder/test.HTML" or alike)

Comment: I changed the path(changed WEB_INF to WEB-INF) and now I get the HTML error that requested source is not available. Is it because my TomCat server is unable to see the HTML file?

Comment: based on the structure you described, src="../WEB_INF/test2.HTML" might do the trick.